kcachegrind can't connect to display
For a school project I have to use Valgrind and other tools to help optimise a program. I'm on macOS 14.0 and using a Lima VM to run the profiling tools, but this is my first time using an environment like this so I'm not familiar with how it all works.
I'm encountering a problem with kcachegrind: after profiling the compiled file with valgrind --tool=callgrind ./file I run kcachegrind callgrind.out.3113 but get the following output:
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 127.0.0.1:10.0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)

I tried reinstalling Qt but it didn't fix the issue. I've also tried a few quick fixes I found online:

XQuartz is running

The ~/.ssh/config file contains the lines
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes


I've tried setting the DISPLAY environment manually with export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:10.0


According to the guide I was given, kcachegrind should open a GUI that visualises the profiling file produced by Valgrind.
Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

How do you connect to your VM? Do you pass -X with your ssh command?

Yes, the command I was using is ssh -X -i “/Users/<user>/.lima/_config/user” -p <port> <user>@127.0.0.1. In the end I managed to solve the issue, the solution was connection to the VM via ssh from XQuartz's inbuilt terminal rather than my machines terminal.
